# In Fabric, how the key used for data encryption is supposed to be shared?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

With FAB-830 implemented in Fabric v1.1, it is now possible for the chaincode to encrypt the data stored in the state.
The idea is: the symmetric encryption key is passed as a transient parameter and is therefore only known to the endorsers.
This allows to run business logic on clear data and upsert encrypted data (such on-chain encryption is impossible in Ethereum and most other blockchains AFAIK).

The part I still miss is: how the organizations which are supposed to share the secret get to know the symmetric key?

Also, even if the endorser get the transient key from the sender as part of the transaction proposal, is there any out-of-the-box way to store it?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peers/endorsers should not actually store the encryption key.  The idea is that the encryption key(s) are managed at the application level and only passed to the peers as required (generally when executing contract logic and not necessarily needed for querying data as the decryption can be done in the application rather than on the peer(s)).

Comment: So basically, you are saying that Fabric doesn't provide any solution at the moment to share and store the keys.

Comment: That's problematic, isn't it? It seems to me a basic requirement that should be taken care of by the framework. Also, surely the endorsing peer should not store the key in the state (that would ruin the point) but as it "sees" it as a transient param, with a code change, any endorsing peer could persist it somewhere with the associated encrypted kvp write set for future use (after tx is committed). Is there not a FAB for that?